# How to encode array to json containing function?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a little problem when I want to generate a json string containing javascript function.
I am using `json_encode()` function and it works well for encoding any object/array to be json string. But, I want to fill one of an element value by a javascript function.
`json_encode()` will always encode my function to string. How do I can remove the `"`(quote)? The quote`"` makes my function be a string.
here's the example:

```
$var['status']     = "oke";
$var['fnFeedback'] = "function (a,b,c){ return a+c.FnSource; }";

echo json_encode($var);
//then the result
{[status:"oke"],[fnFeedback:"function (a,b,c){ return a+c.FnSource; }"]}
//value of fnFeedback of above json is a string
```

How can I make value of fnFeedback be a function?

Comment: you can't (directly) - there's no specific JSON encoding for functions.

Comment: JSON cannot contains functions

Comment: so I have to remove the quotes manually?

Comment: Try to Use eval function of JS..

Comment: no, since your JSON decoder will do that for you, leaving a string.  You'll then have to recognise that the string contains a function body and then pass it either to `new Function()` or `eval` (bleuch) to turn it into an actual function.

Comment: Seriously: don't. Passing functions as JSON strings means using the function constructor _or_ `eval`, both of which make it really easy to exploit your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your sample isn't legal JSON syntax. Suppose it's something like this instead:

```
var input = '{"status":"oke","fnFeedback":"function (a,b,c){return a+c.FnSource;}"}';
```

One way to deal with this is to parse normally and then use `eval` to turn the value of the `fnFeedback` property into a `Function` object. However, using `eval` is usually a last resort (not to mention extremely risky if you aren't in total control of the value being `eval`-ed) and here there's a better approach using a little trick when parsing JSON data.

The trick is that `JSON.parse` accepts a second argument, which should be a function that accepts a key/value pair and returns the result. This will be called for every element that is parsed. Here's one that will turn your serialized function string into an actual function:

```
var result = JSON.parse(input,
    function(key, value) {
        // if value looks like a function definition, make a function
        if (value 
                && typeof value === "string" 
                && value.substr(0,8) == "function")
        {
            var startBody = value.indexOf('{') + 1;
            var endBody = value.lastIndexOf('}');
            var startArgs = value.indexOf('(') + 1;
            var endArgs = value.indexOf(')');

            return new Function(value.substring(startArgs, endArgs),
                                value.substring(startBody, endBody));
        }
        // else just return the value as is
        return value;
    });
```

When this is run, you can then see the results:

> > result['fnFeedback']
>   [Function]
>   > result['fnFeedback'].toString()
>   'function anonymous(a,b,c) {\n return a+c.FnSource; \n}'

A more detailed explanation of how this works can be found [here](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/json-serialize-and-deserialize.html) (from which the above was adapted). Also see [this JavaScript gist](https://gist.github.com/anvaka/3815296) for another (perhaps cleaner) sample code using the same idea (which I have not tested).

Comment: very nice answer - I didn't have the time to explain the difference between `Function` and `eval` earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. JSON means: **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject ***N***otation. It is a serialisation to `String` values of all properties of an Object. Function properties are not serializable. If you deserialize the JSON-string to `Object` you'll have to convert the string containing the function to a real javascript function (e.g. using `eval` or `new Function`).

[**See also ...**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), chapter 5:

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or
>   null

Comment: or even just json.org

Comment: nit-pick: _"A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null"_ <-- but a function **is** an object!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, but it's a _special_ kind of object, that has a constructor, and a prototype chain.

Comment: @Alnitak: I know, just failing to be funny ;-P

Comment: oke, Thanks for the reference!  I'll try to find the solution

Comment: so i have to convert the function to an object, right?

Answer (score 1):

JSON cannot directly represent function bodies.

Given your JSON converted back into a JS object (below called `myObj`) one possibility is to convert the string directly into a function by wrapping it in parentheses (thus converting the function declaration into a function expression) and then passing it to `eval`:

```
var fnFeedback = eval('(' + myObj.fnFeedback + ')';
```

Please note that there are possible security issues with using `eval` - use with extreme caution and do not trust any function body supplied indirectly by third parties.  It's safer to use `Function` instead,  see Ted Hopp's later answer.

Comment: and re-assign the `fnFeedback` to the json, done! :D

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi please accept Ted Hopp's answer - the version using `Function` is far preferable to using `eval` but I didn't have time to write that version earlier.

Comment: Yes, his is more complex, and it is clearer to be understood, but i didn't use it. I just need a little trick to go. But for a common problem, I think Ted Hopp's answer is preferable (as your suggest).